# Open pop up form in edit mode

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb

Is it possible to have a `one2many` field in a form view that when you click it, it will pop open the form view of that `one2many` model but give the user the option to edit and save?

Currently, it pops open the form view of the corresponding model but it doesn't give edit option. Therefore users can only view the details.

I have tried using editable bottom. But this is for inline editing.

Thanks

Below is the example I am facing. If I click on the `consultation_ids` I get a pop-up form without the ability to edit it.

```
    <record id="view_patient_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">medical.record.form</field>
        <field name="model">fhg.patient</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Patient">
                <sheet>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <field style="z-index: 100" name="image_medium" widget="image" class="openerp oe_left oe_avatar" nolabel="1" />
                        <div class="oe_title">
                            <field name="barcode_preview" readonly="1" />
                            <field name="unique_number" string="Ref:" readonly="1" />
                            <field name="legacy_unique_number" string="Legacy ref:" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Outpatient">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <field name="consultation_ids" nolabel="1">
                                            <tree>
                                                <field name="date" string="Date" />
                                                <field name="medical_specialty_id" string="Medical Specialty" />
                                                <field name="consultation_type" string="Consultation Type" />
                                                <field name="medical_staff_id" string="Medical Staff" />
                                                <field name="medical_center_id" string="Medical Center" />
                                                <field name="state" string="State" />
                                            </tree>
                                        </field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Without extra options and not defining an editable tree view, that should be the default. But you have to switch to edit mode in the parent view (the view with the one2many) first. Or i don't get your requirement fully :-/

Comment: Even when the parent view is in edit mode. The one2many stills open read-only child view without "Edit" button provided. Thus the user can only read the data.

Comment: Do you have example code?

Comment: Hi, I have added an XML example. Thanks for your attention. :)

Comment: Please add the `consultation_ids` field declaration

Comment: Have you tried to define a form view together with the tree view?

Comment: @CZoellner Hmm I haven't heard form view together with tree view. Might you point to a sample view in Odoo?

Comment: sale.order form has tree and form for field order_line.

Comment: @CZoellner thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Actually, I found my case is a bit unique. The one2many is computed and the default attributes of read-only for a computed field are 0. This what makes the pop-up form state read-only. Anyway thanks a lot.